# print unicode character on linux using gcc

Tags: c, linux, widechar

I'm trying to print wchar_t string to terminal but the string doesn't show up or it appears as unreadable characters.

I tried on `XUbuntu 22.04` and `gcc (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04.1) 11.3.0` and you can see the sample code here,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main(void)
{
        setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF-8");
    wchar_t sample1[] = { L"Sample TEXT\\自己人自己人人       AZZZZZZZA己中国中中中\n" };
    printf("AAAA\n");
    printf("%ls", L"ABCD");
    printf("%ls", sample1);
    return 0;
}
```

and I compile it using gcc as follow,

```
gcc test.c -fshort-wchar -o test
```

I write the data to a file on Windows as unicode and I should read the file and print it's content on Linux. So wchar_t on Windows is 16bit but on Linux its 32bit that's why I used `-fshort-wchar` gcc flag.

In the output of the above code I can only see "AAAA\n" thats it.

What is the issue with my code? How can I print unicode wchar_t in C properly and be able to read it in my terminal?

I will rephrase my question as suggested in the first comment, I have a file saved as utf-16 on Windows, how do I print it on Linux?

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking XY question? Did you indent to ask "I have a file saved with UTF-16. How do I print it on linux?" ? `I write the data to a file on Windows as unicode` What unicode?

Comment: Do you want windows or linux? Linux does UTF-8 just fine [preferred]. So, _don't_ use unicode `wchar_t` 16 bit chars. It probably won't display properly using `printf` et. al. Just change `L"xxxx"` into `"xxxx"`. With that, the `setlocale` probably isn't needed [unless you're in a non-US locale]. If you have some text file that _is_ [windows] 16 bit unicode, you might want to explicit loop on the file and use an explicit conversion function to convert it to UTF-8. Changing the locale or using wide chars won't work too well with xterm/gnome-terminal without a lot of finagling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the issue with my code?

The issue with your code is that you used `-fshort-wchar` and glibc was compiled to work with 32-bit wchar_t. In turn, `printf("%ls"` accesses the memory as a 32-bit array, while the array has 16-bit elements.

> How can I print unicode wchar_t in C properly and be able to read it in my terminal?

Do not use `-fshort-wchar` or compile anything that you use like C standard library and other libraries that you indent to use with `-fshort-wchar`.

> the data to a file on Windows as unicode and I should read the file and print it's content on Linux

Then you have to know the "unicode" format that windows has written the file in. Once it is known, it is typical use `iconv` command or function to convert the file. You can also use libraries like libunistring or icu to handle unicode.

Comment: Re "*Then you have to know the "unicode" format that windows has written the file in*", "Unicode" refers to UTF-16LE in Windows (while "ANSI" refers to your system's or app's active/ansi code page, e.g. Windows-1252 for the typical US machine).

Answer (score 0):

Each stream, such as `stdout` has an *orientation* for `char` or `wchar_t` and initially can handle either one.  Once the first I/O occurs, such as `printf("AAAA\n");` orientation is established.  In this case to `char`.

To potentially subsequently print to another orientation, first re-open the stream.

> Each stream has an orientation. After a stream is associated with an external file, but before any
> operations are performed on it, the stream is without orientation.
> Once a wide character input/output function has been applied to a stream without orientation, the stream becomes a wide-oriented stream. Similarly, once a byte input/output function has been applied to a stream without orientation, the stream becomes a byte-oriented stream. Only a call to the `freopen` function or the `fwide` function can otherwise alter the orientation of a stream. (A successful call to `freopen` removes any orientation. C17dr §7.21.2 4.

```
printf("AAAA\n");
FILE *f = freopen(NULL, "w", stdout);
if (f == NULL) Handle_failure();
printf("%ls", L"ABCD");
```

---

In investigating I/O issues, it is useful to test the return values.

```
int retval = printf("AAAA\n");
assert(retval >= 0);
retval = printf("%ls", L"ABCD");
assert(retval >= 0);
```